# Google Sheet Query SUM exclude IF is not blank

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

In the tab **"Invoice WholeSale"**, cell **"B3"** I need a query to SUM the tabs:

- **"Stock Warehouse Moves"**
- **"Stock Shop Moves "**

but grouped by the column WholeSale and IGNORE the rows without text in this column.

here is [my Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oPsJglgNFvwdm_BS9Jd4_xUMXwtk8KbsKZf29jOwZuA/edit#gid=2027987507/)

For exmaple I expect from tab:

**"Stock Warehouse Moves"**

[image: 0]

and from tab 
**"Stock Shop Moves"**

[image: 0]

I try this but doesn't work:

```
=query('Stock Warehouse Moves'!A3:I,"select H, sum(B) where (H is not null) group by H"{'Stock Shop Moves'!A3:I,"select H, sum(B) where (H is not null) group by H"})
```

and this, but doesn't show the data properly:

```
=query('Stock Shop Moves'!A3:I,"select H, sum(B) where (H is not null) group by H")
```

I expected the next grouped by WholeSale:

[image: 0]

Comment: can you add the desired output?

Comment: yes, is the last picture. Like you can see Grouped by: "Book Store 1" and "Book Store 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY({'Stock Warehouse Moves'!A3:H; 'Stock Shop Moves'!A3:H},
 "select Col1,count(Col8),Col8 
  where Col8 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col8 
  label count(Col8)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: try: `=QUERY({'Stock Warehouse Moves'!A3:H; 'Stock Shop Moves'!A3:H},
 "select Col1,count(Col8),Col8 
  where Col8 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col8 
  order by Col8 asc
  label count(Col8)''", 0)`